# Code reusability in React Native, Ionic, Flutter and NativeScript(write once, use everywhere)

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, flutter, cross-platform, nativescript

It is the first time that I write that kind of question here so please excuse me if my question is not okay.

I am learning some new cross platform frameworks. I am interesting in **Ionic**(version 4), **Flutter**, React Native and **NativeScript**. Precisely, I would like to understand the concept of *code reusability* for each framework. How do they apply reusability? In which matrix and what are the consequences?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you define "code reusability"?

Comment: @RémiRousselet https://www.quora.com/What-is-code-reusability as mentioned here. Some technics or patterns that each framework uses and applies code reusability.

Answer (score 5):

In react-native you have create any component used any screen. for example I used InputText component for reusability.

**InputField.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextInput, View, StyleSheet, Text,Image } from "react-native";

export class InputField extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      textentry,
      keytype,
      isvalid,
      errormsg,
      returnkey,
      textplaceholder,
      underlinecolor,
      onchangetext
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder={textplaceholder}
          keyboardType={keytype}
          placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
          underlineColorAndroid={underlinecolor}
          secureTextEntry={textentry}
          ref={(input) => this.props.inputRef && this.props.inputRef(input)}
          returnKeyType={returnkey}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
            if (returnkey != 'done') {
                this.props.onSubmitEditing(event)
            }
        }}
          onChangeText={text => {
            this.props.onText(text);
          }}
        />
        <View>
          {!isvalid ? (
            <Text style={styles.errormsg}>{errormsg}</Text>
          ) : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    width: 300,
    color: "#ffffff",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignSelf: "center"
  },
  errormsg: {
    color: "#ff0000",
    marginLeft: 60
  },
});
export default InputField;
```

Use this InputField component to screen
**Myscreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import { InputField } from "../component/InputField";
 render() {
    return (
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<InputField
            keytype="default"
            textplaceholder="Enter First Name"
            textentry={false}
            returnkey="next"
            isvalid={this.state.firstNameValid}
            errormsg={this.state.errormsgtext}
            underlinecolor={this.state.underLineColorFirstName}
            onText={text => {
              this.setState({ firstName: text });
            }}
            onSubmitEditing={event => {
              this.inputs["phone"].focus();
            }}
          />
</View>
)}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Talking about code sharing between Web and Mobile regarding NativeScript here are a few things to know:

> Disclaimer: I am part of the NativeScript team

1. First it is only possible via Angular, there is not code sharing if you prefer to use pure JS or TypeScript
2. Second the portion of the code shared between the Web, iOS and Android is dependant on the functionality of your app. Meaning that if you rely heavily on platform specific functionality both for the UI and the code behind logic it is possible to not be able achieve full code shared, yet there are ways to overcome such scenarios and again be able to share common services.
3. Third the idea of code sharing with NativeScript is that if you have a specific code for a "platform" (Web, iOS and/or Android) you simply create additional file with a specific file name. For example if you have an Angular component named `home.component.ts` you should have one file containing its HTML for the Web part and one for the Mobile part so you simply create both `home.component.html` and `home.component.tns.html`. Similar approach is used for other non component files like css and angular services etc.

The technique that is used to achieve code sharing in NativeScript with Web is with the use of Angular schematics specifically for NativeScript.

The topic of exactly how code sharing is achieve is quite log so I would suggest you to read [this](https://blog.angular.io/apps-that-work-natively-on-the-web-and-mobile-9b26852495e7) blog post that introduces the code sharing between Web, iOS and Android with NativeSript. For a getting started steps I recommend the official documentation [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/intro?_ga=2.261539151.314409381.1554968498-2118632387.1549027197).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the documentation. I already read it. What I may confuse is: the approach of NativeScript for code sharing between web and mobile apps supports the idea of Write once, use anywhere? In the official website, only a distinction between web and mobile apps is done. I mean what about implementation and code sharing between iOS and Android platforms?

Comment: Thank from our website "NativeScript is designed to publish applications to both iOS and Android from the same codebase.". What this means in practice is that by design the idea behind NativeScript is to provide common API (using TS/JS wrappers) for all common functionality between iOS and Android. Example: when you write `<Button />`, this uses our wrapper which knows to create `UIButton` on iOS and `android.widget.Button`. This means that you have 100% code shared when creating a `Button`. This is true for any kind of functionality that has its own wrapper (provided with plugin)

Answer (score 2):

About React Native, it works with something called `Components`. You may create a component for each thing you could imagine. The best of having components is that they are reusables. For example, I can create a button in a component and then export that same button to other apps or screens.

Comment: Hi. So this is a metric about reusing UI components? What about the other frameworks? Does React Native follows a specific pattern to reuse code?

Comment: Unfortunately I only can advise you about React Native because I haven't touch the others.
React Native is like to program orientated to the creation of components. You create a UI component or a library of specific functions and you can port that to anywhere in a react native project. Sorry about how I explain (i'm not an english man and neither a teacher but I tried my best)

Comment: No. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it, no problem. But those components need to be created and restyled by you, right? And of course you need to take care of the 2 diff platforms. So code reusability is not a lot by React Native. On the other hand, React Native uses JS and React JSX. So Redux can be used right?

Comment: No, you are wrong. Having account that React Native use the same JS code for both platform (except in a bit cases) you will have only to code 1 component. e.g: I need a Modal Window that could list items? Then, you model it in react native creating properties for that component in a way that when you use it you will have to pass the data to that component (an array in that case for example) but nothing else is required. In each screen you uses your modalWindow you just will need the data it needs and would be used easy.

Comment: It's like to create your components, define what they need to be used and then port them in any code. While you port it well and pass it the data it needs it would be usable. Redux is about to use the state of the app. In redux you save the state like the language, if a person is logged etc. And depending of that the app do 1 thing or another.